# Selecting Closest Match using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble selecting the closest match. I already tried `.closest`, `.next`, and `.nextall`; I also tried using (this), but I think I'm using them incorrectly.

Here's what I want to acheive:
When `.show` is clicked, the closest `.list-content` will toggle and the closest toggleClass icon-rotate-180 too.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="list-menu">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="show">
            Date of Operations 
            <i class="icon-chevron-down pull-right"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-content">Hidden Content until Clicked</li>

    <li class="list-menu">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="show">
            Date of Operations 
            <i class="icon-chevron-down pull-right"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-content">Hidden Content until Clicked</li>
</ul>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".list-content").hide();
            $(".show").click(function() {
                $(".icon-chevron-down").toggleClass("icon-rotate-180");
                $(".list-content").toggle();
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your HTML is invalid as you cannot have a `div` element as a direct child of a `ul`. With that in mind, try this:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="list-menu">
        <a href="#" class="show">
            Date of Operations 
            <i class="icon-chevron-down pull-right"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="list-content">Hidden Content until Clicked</div>
    </li>

    <li class="list-menu">
        <a href="#" class="show">
            Date of Operations 
            <i class="icon-chevron-down pull-right"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="list-content">Hidden Content until Clicked</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```js
$(".show").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".icon-chevron-down", this).toggleClass("icon-rotate-180");
    $(".list-content", $(this).closest('li')).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Hey Rory, it's still not working: http://206.130.117.31/test/ (Just the arrows are working).

Comment: I would change the last line to `$(this).parent("li").next(".list-content").toggle()`

Comment: @BlakeSimpson that wouldn't work with my example as I changed the HTML structure be valid.

Comment: @BowenCheng it doesn't work because your HTML structure is different to that in my example.

Answer (score 0):

1. `ul`/`li` is the wrong case here. The second `li` is in relation to the first `li`. Please use `dl`, `dd` and `dt` instead - this is not the perfect match but better than `ul`/`li`!
2. `a` is for links but you dont call a url. Please use the `dd` itself or a `span` so you dont need the `javascript:void(0);` and no `e.preventDefault();`.

   Date of Operations
             
         
         Hidden Content until Clicked

   ```
     <dd class="list-menu show">
         Date of Operations
         <i class="icon-chevron-down pull-right"></i>
     </dd>
     <dt class="list-content">Hidden Content until Clicked</dt>
   ```

   $(".show").click(function(e) {
             $(this).closest(".icon-chevron-down").toggleClass("icon-rotate-180");
             $(this).next("dt.list-content").toggle();
         });

(i copied a part of RoyMcCrossan's answer from [Selecting Closest Match using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18184625/selecting-closest-match-using-jquery))

*Sorry structure broken, looks like a bug in Stackoverflow.*